# How to pass a variable to a psql call in a batch file?

Tags: postgresql, windows, batch-file, psql

I have a batch file that I'm attempting to use to do database backups. In order to try and make this reusable I have parameterised most of the inputs such as:

- Database
- User
- Password
- Schema

and so on.

This is what it looks like

```
@echo on

    SET dbPath=%~1
    SET dbHost=%~2
    SET dbName=%~3
    SET dbUser=%~4
    SET dbPassword=%~5
    SET backupFile=%~6
    SET schema=%~7
    SET databaseSQL=%~8

    SET today=%DATE:~-4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%
    
@REM -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :Setup Logging
@REM -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    IF NOT EXIST "%dbPath%\logs\" mkdir "%dbPath%\logs"
    
    CD %dbPath%\logs\
    
    IF NOT EXIST restore_log_%schema%_%today%.txt (
        type NUL > restore_log_%schema%_%today%.txt
    )
        
    SET logFile="%dbPath%\logs\restore_log_%schema%_%today%.txt"
    
@REM -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :Restore schema
@REM -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    echo Started: %date% %time% >> %logFile%

    cd ..
    
    SET dbPassword=%dbPassword%
    

    psql -h %dbHost% -p "PASSWORD" -U %dbUser% -d %dbName% -c "DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS %schema%" >> %logFile%
        
    psql -h %dbHost% -p "PASSWORD" -U %dbUser% -d "dbSUB2" < %backupFile%  2>&1|more >> %logFile%
    
    echo Finished: %date% %time% >> %logFile%
```

However, when passing in `%schema%` within double quotes the value of the parameter is converted to lowercase, which is a problem as my tables follow the naming convention of `tblTableName`. This means the statement says correctly that it cannot find the table as it legitimately doesn't exist.

I have tried using single quotes but that turned out strangely. I also tried the `:f` flag to just run a separate file but then it did not recognise the variable, the only time it worked was when the file only contained `SELECT :variable`.

Ideally I'd like to use the first method but I'm unsure how to tell the psql command to not convert my database schema to lowercase.

Comment: "*as my tables follow the naming convention of `tblTableName`*" which is a mistake to begin with. And you just found another reason not to do this. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: try doubling the double quotes inside the parameter string: `-c "DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS ""%schema%"""`

Comment: As I inherited this process I wasn't in a position to change table names but I will definitely factor this in in the future. Can I ask as a general rule of thumb, how did you know it would need double double quotes?

Comment: Well, that's the way Windows escapes double quotes on the command line. It is completely independent of Postgres (or psql)

Comment: Your double quote theory was correct so if you write it as an answer I'll mark it as correct. Escaping strings is definitely underrated knowledge.